# How to remove the dotted outline for the header of Expander control in WPF (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to remove the dotted outline for the header of Expander control in WPF (C#)?

I tried by making FocusVisualStyle to null but no luck. Is there any other approach?

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="373" Width="669">
    <Expander FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Expanded="expander1_Expanded" Focusable="False" Foreground="DarkBlue" Header="My Header" Height="219" Name="expander1" Width="525">

.....
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the changes to this part (see the full template at the bottom of message)
This example makes a thicker red stroke:

```
`<Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>`
```

This is the original template for the expander as captured by Blend - it will automatically apply to all expanders in that window.

```
    `<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <TransformCollection>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                                </TransformCollection>
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <TransformCollection>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                                </TransformCollection>
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <TransformCollection>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                </TransformCollection>
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="StyledExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderWithDifferentFocusRectagle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                              <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>`
```

Comment: Why do we have to basically create a new control to simply change one property? Why does Expander define its own hard-coded focus rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the FocusVisualStyle not only for Expander but also for it's template parts, e.g. change template using Blend and see what template parts also have focus style.

Comment: I am naive to WPF .SO could you provide a simple example for it? Should I create a custom control for expander ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The solution that worked for me is to handle the `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` event

```
    private void Expander_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This is not really a great solution, although it might work. Modifying the styles is the way to go, as this is what one would be looking for whenever to change it back. I would not ever relate this issue to an event handler!

Comment: You can create a behavior for this if you want and attach it by using styles. The key is to name your classes/methods accordingly to what you're trying to achieve, and/or put a note in the comment. The above code suggests how to work around the issue, but to make it pretty/easy to maintain is up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely the OP is interested but in case anyone else is...

Here is an alternative approach. I wrapped walking the visual tree in an extension method and set the FocusVisualStyle of ToggleButtons to null. The only ToggleButtons in my application are in Expanders but I guess you could look for Expanders first if you wanted.

I call this.RemoveFocusVisualStyleFromAllExpanders() in the Loaded event of my Window.

```
public static class WindowExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveFocusVisualStyleFromAllExpanders(this Window window)
    {
        RecursivelyDelveVisualTreeRemovingFocusVisualStyleFromToggleButtons(window);
    }

    private static void RecursivelyDelveVisualTreeRemovingFocusVisualStyleFromToggleButtons(DependencyObject d)
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i);
            var toggleButton = child as ToggleButton;
            if (toggleButton != null)
            {
                toggleButton.FocusVisualStyle = null;
            }
            else
            {
                RecursivelyDelveVisualTreeRemovingFocusVisualStyleFromToggleButtons(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```